# Codeigniter 4 - Emojis stored in database differ from they are displayed in html page

Tags: database, codeigniter, character-encoding, emoji

I am new in Codeigniter 4, and I am working on a tutorial related to Emojis.
I got the problem that I spent a week on the internet with the hope to find out a solution. Unfortunately, nothing can solve the issue. Hope you can help me out.

Issue description:

I followed the link from Github [emojionearea](https://github.com/mervick/emojionearea) that assisted me with creating an Emoji picker.

It run perfectly until I submitted an emoji to database and retrieved it from DB to show in a webpage.

I selected an emoji, for example the Man Technologist emoji, it was showed in the input field as One Emoji (see the screenshot "Before submitting" below), which is what I want.

[Before Submitting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liyA0.png)

After I submitted it to the database and retrieved to display in a page, I realised that there are two emojis have been saved (see "After Submitting" screenshot below).
[After Submitting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ll30y.png)

That is the issue I want to be helped.

Following is my Database Settings:

I set DB, DB tables and columns to the charset `utf8mb4` and collations to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.
I run `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';` in phpmyadmin SQL to see the current status of my Database with the Charset set. It shows as below:
[DB Charset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xunJB.png)

In the file Database.php in Config folder, I set as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6H4Qy.png)

In my php view, I included the code `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8">` in the header.

Done descripting my issue.

Please help me go throught and fix this problem.
Thank you!

I tried to change to many charsets for database.
I was expecting that Database got exactly as the emoji displayed in a page before being submitted to Database.

Comment: While it is great to see your screen results in an image, please do not present data structure in an image, but as text. Please do not use screenshots of your code or error messages and do not link to external sources. Screenshots are hard to read on mobile devices, they cannot be searched and none of us can copy, paste and run an image, links can get obsolete. Code should be included as text in the question itself. For more on this see 
[**Why may I not upload images of code**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#28

Answer (score 0):

It says on the Emojionearea github page that `"The end result is a secure text/plain in which the image icons will be replaced with their Unicode analogues."` So what is saving to the database is the unicode version of the Emojione image you picked.

To convert the unicode back to an Emojione image, install the PHP Toolkit for the Emojione library:
https://github.com/joypixels/emoji-toolkit/blob/master/INSTALLATION.md

```
composer require joypixels/emoji-toolkit
```

Then use this toolkit to convert the unicode back to an image:
https://github.com/joypixels/emoji-toolkit/blob/master/examples/PHP.md

```
use JoyPixels\Client;
use JoyPixels\Ruleset;

$client = new Client(new Ruleset());
echo $client->toImage($inputText);
```

Emojionearea seems to be using an older version (3.1.2) of Emojione by default, so you might want to create an extension of the `Client` class to set the toolkit to the same version, as the images for the various versions are slightly different:

```
<?php

namespace App\Libraries;

use JoyPixels\Client;

class Emoji extends Client
{
    public $emojiVersion = '3.1'; // 3.1.2 does not seem to work
}
```

Then use this class instead to convert the unicode string into an image:

```
use App\Libraries\Emoji;
use JoyPixels\Ruleset;

$client = new Emoji(new Ruleset());
echo $client->toImage($inputText);
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer!
I followed what you guided above. However, it still shows both emojis and extra image icons of alternatives in front of the emoji.
Also, the version is quite old, so I am looking at JoyPixels to get more ideas on emojis with its assistance. 
Thank you again and have a good holiday and Happy New Year!

Comment: How strange. I tested this with a form and controller method and it didn't give me any extra icons, didn't test with a database though. I'd be happy to look into this some more if you want to share more code. Happy holidays to you too!

Comment: Hi Marleen,
I had a bit of time to play with that emoji issue, and I just changed a code in the script to save emojis. It is saveEmojisAs: "image". Although it displays a link in the input field, the result is still what I want because I can hide the link from it.  Just want to share this with you. 
Now I am encountering AJAX in Codeigniter 4, which I will post a question after this. Hope I can get a solution. Thank you, Marleen!